# Interesting Issue found when using WCF Data Service Client Library to query data from a WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, wcf-data-services

I have a simple data model with 3 tables (Account, Contact, and User) with the following relationships:

> User -> Account (1 - Many) Account -> Contact (Many - 1)

I am exposing my data via an OData (v3) WCF Data Service, which is consumed by a .NET client that uses the WCF Data Service Client Library. I used the Add Service utility to generate the client proxy code to call the data service.

All methods in the client class uses the class's single `DataServiceContext` object for calling the web service. i.e.:

```
DC.WhEntities svcClient = new DC.WhEntities(new Uri(BaseUrl));
```

What I am having a hard time trying to figure out is why the same query request to the service starts failing after the 6th time. I have literally tried all possible ways to construct a call to the data service:

**First approach:**

```
DataServiceQuery<DC.User> users = svcClient.Users.Expand("Accounts");
QueryOperationResponse<DC.User> response = users.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<DC.User>;
var user = response.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == long.Parse(key.ToString()));
```

**Second approach:**

```
string queryString = string.Format("Users({0}L)?$expand=Accounts", key.ToString());
foreach (var user in response) {...}
```

The last statement in both of the above solution starts failing with a message below after it has executed successfully **6**  times in a row:

```
The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom element or belongs to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' namespace.

**StackTrace:**
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateODataMessageReader(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Boolean projectionQuery, ODataPayloadKind& payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateMaterializerForMessage(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Type materializerType, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Materialize(ResponseInfo responseInfo, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, String contentType, IODataResponseMessage message, ODataPayloadKind expectedPayloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ProcessResult[TElement](ProjectionPlan plan)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
```

When this happens, my WCF Data Service just stopped working and returns a response with

> error on line 1 at column 83: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values.

I am not sure if I am missing anything fundamental or if I'm constructing the WCF Data Service Client request incorrectly or if there is something on the WCF Data Service side that doesn't like the same client requesting the same thing more than 6 times.

I've already spent a few days and I meant 3+ days trying to figure this out. I am new to WCF Data Service and I thought I could learn from this tutorial, but so far I got more pain than gain.

Comment: Please use some HTTP tracing tool (like Fiddler) to grab the response which fails and share it with us here.

Comment: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom element or belongs to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' namespace.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateODataMessageReader(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Boolean projectionQuery, ODataPayloadKind& payloadKind)\r\n

Comment: at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateMaterializerForMessage(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Type materializerType, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Materialize(ResponseInfo responseInfo, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, String contentType, IODataResponseMessage message, ODataPayloadKind expectedPayloadKind)\r\n

Comment: at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ProcessResult[TElement](ProjectionPlan plan)\r\n at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)"}

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking at this, Vitek!

Comment: Were you able to capture the HTTP trace? The exception itself can mean several different things.

Comment: Here is the trace of the error: w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=http://localhost/sapi/api/accounts, Message='http://localhost/sapi/api/accounts' w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Accounts', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='WH.Sapi.Services.Controllers.AccountsController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='WH.Sapi.Services.Controllers.AccountsController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController

Comment: w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'Get(AccountGetReq request)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Value read='WH.Sapi.ServiceModels.Types.AccountGetReq'', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'request' bound to the value 'WH.Sapi.ServiceModels.Types.AccountGetReq'', Operation=FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: request=WH.Sapi.ServiceModels.Types.AccountGetReq', Operation=HttpActionBinding.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in WH.Dapi.Dal.Repository.Implementations.dll
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : peration=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync, Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom element or belongs to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices'namespace.

Comment: at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateODataMessageReader(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Boolean projectionQuery, ODataPayloadKind& payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateMaterializerForMessage(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Type materializerType, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom..ctor(ResponseInfo responseInfo, QueryComponents queryComponents,

Comment: ProjectionPlan plan, String contentType, IODataResponseMessage message, ODataPayloadKind expectedPayloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.CreateMaterializer(ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ProcessResult[TElement](ProjectionPlan plan)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance

Comment: w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=500 (InternalServerError), Method=GET, Url=http://localhost/sapi/api/accounts, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AccountsController.Dispose
The thread '<No Name>' (0x368c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it still doesn't help. Please use a tool like Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and grab the raw HTTP request and response which causes the failure. The HTTP headers and the body content. That should help. Also, are you sure you're using the WCF Data Services? JsonMediaTypeFormatter is not used by WCF Data Services.

Comment: You can also see from the traces above that there was an error on the server (500 InternalServerError). You could try attaching a debugger to the service and stop on that exception to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried setting logMessagesAtTransportLevel to false and still got the error.

Then i remembered seeing this issue before when I had an assembly conflict. I went and created a brand new service and this solved my problem even when I had logMessagesAtTransportLevel set to true on my client. This ensured me that the problem was the service.

Although my solution solved my problem, I still don't know the exact issue and I already ran out of time to find it out. However, It is good to see that people are willing to help out and I truly appreciate the effort.

Thanks everyone again for your help.

Qster123.

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing similar issue, suddenly my server started (maybe some updates inflicted this, yet the cause is unknown) to return bad responses. If I start my server it works for some time, lets say responds to few requests in a normal manner and then starts to break xml structure of the OData feeds, resulting in `<`, hexadecimal value `0x3C`, is an invalid attribute character. `Line 2, position 72. exception`.

**SOLUTION:**

I solved the problem by following [this feed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/74813783-8666-40c4-a9fd-7953f7b6849c/)

If you have WCF tracing configured, make sure `logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"` is turned off, otherwise you will experience this issue.